# Finding the conjugate of a complex number with complex exponent

Tags: complex-numbers

In my Maths textbook, I am given the following rules of complex conjugation:

$$(z_1 \pm z_2)^* = z_1^* \pm z_2^*$$

$$(z_1 z_2)^* = z_1* z_2*$$

$$(\frac{z_1}{z_2})^* = \frac{z_1*}{z_2*}$$

And am told that from these rules it is implied that the conjugate of any complex number can be found by simply changing the signs of the imaginary component, for example:

$$\left[ (a + ib)^{(c+id)} \right]^* = (a- ib)^{c-id}$$

I don't see how this is implied. If the exponent was real then I could consider it as a series of complex numbers multiplied together and flip the signs on each imaginary component by flipping the sign on the base. By the second rule this would find the conjugate of the whole. But with a complex exponent, this line of reasoning breaks down.

Comment: sorry that is a typo. I've fixed it now, should be a $c$ in place of $a$ in the exponent of the LHS

Comment: How do you define $z^{z'}$ where $z$ and $z'$ are complex numbers ?

Comment: Chances are you misunderstood what you were told. If you take the powers in the sense of principal values, then the statement is obviously false, since for example $\,\overline{(-1)^{1/2}} = -i \ne i = \left(\overline{-1}\right)^{\overline{1/2}}\,$. If you take the powers in the sense of multi-valued functions, then it's no longer about *one* complex number.